# Form Closing Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, formclosing

I have a base form class that I have my forums inherit. Is it possible to execute the code from the base form before I execute the code in the inherited forms? I have a check to see if they want to close in the base class and I want nothing to execute till they say yes to the popup form. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exact behavior I wanted, I added two events in my base Closing event. One for right after the check and a second after the code has been executed. I then replaced the FormClosing Event on the Inherited class to use both events. This approach gave me more freedom then just to call the mybase.OnFormClosing

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are already setting the e.Cancel property to true or false in the FormClosing event in your base class, you would just have to check the e.Cancel value in the inherited form:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
  MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)

  If Not e.Cancel Then
    MessageBox.Show("Doing Stuff")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Both of these solutions cause my program to go through the close event twice. Is this normal?

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer Yes, it will run the base closing code, and then your inherited base closing code.  Post your code if you need help with that because we can't see what your code looks like.

Comment: It is almost the same as your posted code. It will execute the MessageBox and than come in again show the messagebox again. I guess I can add a Boolean to stop it the second time has it runs through the base class after the inherited class

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer Then somewhere in your code you are calling it twice.  `MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)` will call the closing code in your base class.  Do both closing codes have a MessageBox?  They probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling the event in your subclass, override the OnFormClosing method. Then you can let the base class implementation do as it chooses. Then do your stuff.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
    'my stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Both of these solutions cause my program to go through the close event twice. Is this normal?